# What is proper input element description for this structure in direct3d 11 to input assembler state?

Tags: c++, windows, directx-11, hlsl, direct3d11

I have this following struct which I use to describe vertexes to input assembler stage:

```
struct Vertex3D
{
  XMFLOAT3 Position;      // position x, y, z
  XMFLOAT4 Color;    // color r, g, b, a
};
```

I know I could use

```
{"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
```

To describe this structure if my position was of type `XMFLOAT2`.

Now I want to extend my struct into 3D space and I have tried to set the desriptor as follows:

```
{"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
```

and my vertex shader is as follows (probably the simplest one possible)

```
void VertexShaderFunction( in float4 posIn : POSITION, in float4 colorIn : COLOR, out float4   posOut : SV_POSITION, out float4 colorOut : COLOUR ){
    posOut = posIn;
    colorOut = colorIn;
}
```

But changing the z coordinate in position doesn't seem to have any effect in the rendering of vertexes. So what would be the correct descriptor to bind into input assembler stage vertex buffer?

Comment: That looks fine to me for the position element. There is possibly an issue with your vertex shader or projection matrix

Comment: @megadan Also I'm planning to take the projection matrixes in to the vertex shader as `float4x4`. What would I need to add to my input descriptor then?

Comment: @megadan Would I just add four identifiers (one for each row of matrix) as follows: `{"INPUTMATRIX", rowNumber, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}`?

Comment: The projection matrix is normally passed via a global shader parameter, because it is equal for all vertices and can be shared.